# Bootstrap 3.3.4 Tooltip not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I've searched for several hours and tried every hint (here and at other sites) that I found, but I just don't get the tooltip to appear.

Modals, form Validation, ... everything else works fine.

This is the js.files I include at the end of the page, right before the closing body-Tag:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is the Trigger-Code for the Tooltip-Element put below the above mentioned links

```
<script language="Javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tooltipTest').tooltip({
    placement: 'top',
    trigger: 'hover',
    selector: 'a'
  });
}); // end document.ready    
</script>
```

And this ist the HTML

```
<a id="tooltipTest" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="test Tooltip" title="Titel">Test-Tooltip</a>
```

Doesn't work. Drives me crazy...

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: getUserData() und setUserData() sollten nicht mehr verwendet werden. Verwenden Sie stattdessen WeakMap oder element.dataset. requestNotifier.js:64
ReferenceError: $ is not defined {base_url}:24
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1
http://{base_url}/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
getPreventDefault() sollte nicht mehr verwendet werden. Verwenden Sie stattdessen defaultPrevented. jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3

Answer (score 0):

try to change jquery version to 1.9.1 or lesser, mostly its because of jquery diff versions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: tried, didn't change a thing, created more warnings in console (see above)

Comment: @hbergman, you are getting $ is not define, are you sure you have linked correct jquery link on html and then using $ sign, or have you tried jQuery instead of $ sign

Comment: @ankhit Sanghvi, yeah, noticed that, too as I copied the console. Fixed that by moving the $(document).ready from head to below jquery-Link. Still doesn't work. uaaahhhhh!

Comment: @karlingen :( have to look into script now.